# How to add a code snippet/block to Swagger api using annotations (SpringBoot app)?

Tags: java, spring, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen, springfox

I need to add a code snippet (javascript, for instance) with some implementation details to a desired method description.

I've tried to use *ApiOperation(value = "method name", notes = "the actual code which I want to show goes here")*, but It doesn't allow to format string in *notes* parameter.

Is it possible to use formatted code blocks using annotations in Swagger in Spring Boot application?